# C++ Constructor by Value

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Assuming I have the following (invalid) code:

```
struct A {
  A(A) {};
};
```

MSVC gives me:

```
error C2652: 'A' : illegal copy constructor: first parameter must not be a 'A'
```

Why does the compiler detect this as copy constructor, and not a regular constructor?

Chapter 12.8.2 of the C++ Standard says:

> A non-template constructor for class
>   X
>   is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type
>   **X&**
>   ,
>   **const X&**
>   ,
>   **volatile X&**
>   or
>   **const volatile X&**

I would expect that the compiler detects the above method as regular constructor, just like

```
struct A {
  A(B) {};
};
```

whereas B is another class.

Where is this behaviour defined?

Comment: on GCC 4.9.2, error: invalid constructor; you probably meant 'A (const A&)'

Comment: Probably because this is a common enough error when people try to make their own copy constructor that MSVS tried to be nice and let them know.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I like that.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking too, but I was looking for proof. There seems to be no definite answer though, so I guess I'll have to live with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N4140 [[class.copy]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.copy#6)

> A declaration of a constructor for a class `X` is ill-formed if its first parameter is of type (optionally cv-qualified) `X` and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

Comment: Thanks, this is kinda what I was looking for. I believe the error message is just misleading then

Comment: Preempted me by what, 9 seconds? :P

Comment: This states what we all know, the constructor is an error.  The question is why does MSVS think it is a copy constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver this kinda proves that the compiler error message is simply wrong, though, probably to prevent people writing invalid copy constructors.

Comment: FWIW, gcc's message is "invalid constructor; you probably meant ‘A (const A&)’" and clang uses similar wording to MSVC: "copy constructor must pass its first argument by reference"